# Definition of a class's private integral constant: in the header or in the cpp file?

Tags: c++

Subject has been addressed mostly here ([Where to declare/define class scope constants in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043493/where-to-declare-define-class-scope-constants-in-c))
and in particular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043667/2436175).

What I would like to fully understand, in case of integral constants, is there any difference between:

```
//In the header
class A {
private:
static const int member = 0; //Declaration and definition
};
```

And:

```
//In the header
class A {
private:
static const int member; //Only declaration
};

//In the cpp
const int A::member = 0; //Definition
```

(I understand that the second might have the advantage that if I change the value of the constant, I have to recompile only one file)

Side questions:
What happens for example with an inline method defined in the header that access `member`? Will it simply be not inlined? What would happens if, going to one extreme, all methods were defined in the header file as inline methods and all constants were defined in the cpp file?

**Edit:**

My apologizes: I thought it was not necessary, but I missed the fact that the member is static. My question stays, but now the code is legal.

Comment: The second is illegal.

Comment: I don't think the second version should even compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Then there is a problem with Mingw.

Comment: In your code you define constant members. But not integral constants inside your class. Do you mean `static const int`?

Comment: Could someone clarify why this is upvoted? @Antonio, could you clarify your question (i.e. make the code compilable)?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, please check my edit

Comment: @JanHerrmann Sorry, please check my edit

Comment: Now one is static and the other isn't. That's a big difference. If they both are, there's not much point in the second, really.

Comment: @chris Is that a big difference also for a private member? Anyway, I have added static to keep the question more focused.

Comment: @Antonio, No the access specifier changes nothing in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, as it was before the question was changed to make it static, it's a non-static member, then it can only be initialised in the constructor's initialiser list or (since 2011) in the member's declaration. Your second example was ill-formed.

If it's static, then you need a definition if it's *odr-used*: roughly speaking, if you do anything that requires its address rather than just its value. If you only use the value, then the first example is fine. But note that the comment is wrong - it's just a declaration, not a definition.

If you do need a definition, then it's up to you whether you specify the value in the declaration or the definition. Specifying it in the declaration allows better scope for optimisation, since the value is always available when the variable is used. Specifying it in the definition gives better encapsulation, only requiring one translation unit to be recompiled if it changes.

> What happens for example with an inline method defined in the header that access member? Will it simply be not inlined?

There's no reason why accessing a data object defined in another translation unit should prevent a function from being inlined.

Comment: "There's no reason why accessing a data object defined in another translation unit should prevent a function from being inlined." So, in one case it will use the address, and in another case it will be able to use the value itself at compile time, possibly performing some optimizations?

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, if the value isn't available to the compiler at the point of use (and the compiler doesn't have suitable whole-program optimisations) then it will have to be loaded from memory at run-time. That may be less optimal than a hard-coded constant.

Answer (score 2):

This is the question of data hiding. Whether you want to unveil internal class fields or not. If you are shipping a classes library and want to hide the implementation details then it is better to show in the interface as few entities as possible, then even a declaration of the private field `member` is too much.

I would just declare this value as a static variable inside a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 2):

There are two points of view to take into account, namely visibility and addressing.

Note that the two are orthogonal, for you can actually declare the variable as initialized and still define it in a translation unit so it has an effective address in memory.

**Visibility**

Visibility affects the usage of the variable, and has some technical impacts.

For usage in *template code* as a non-type template parameter, the value must be visible at the point of use. Also, in C++11, this might be necessary for `constexpr` usage. Otherwise, it is not *necessary* that the value be visible.

Technically a visible value can trigger optimizations from the compiler. For example `if (A::member)` is trivially false so the test can be elided. This is generally referred to as *Constant Propagation*. While this may seem a good thing, at first glance, there is a profound impact though: all clients of the header file potentially depends on this value, and thus any change to this value means they should be recompiled. If you deliver this header as part of a shared library, this means that changing this value breaks the ABI.

**Addressing**

The rule here is quite simple: if the variable can be addressed (either passed by pointer or reference), then it needs to reside somewhere in memory. This requires a *definition* in *one* translation unit.